# ECCP (Elastix Call Center Protocol) Java-based implementation

Tags: java, integration, asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I've been working in a Java-based version of [Elastix Call Center Protocol](http://pt.slideshare.net/elastixorg/the-elastix-call-center-protocol-revealed) for something around 6 months and I need some help.

Everything I found on the Internet was implemented in PHP and, in the most of case, very poor examples.

I even found an implementation in Java in **SourceForge** but it seems to be abandoned for 10 years.

My points are:

In my app I have to write campaigns and queues directly into Asterisk and Elastix database; there isn't an Eccp operation to do that, according to Eccp Docs.

I wasn't able to create a campaign through Eccp protocol either, because it seems that Eccp doesn't support that kind of operation.

And many other issues. I'm trying to work around these problems mixing Java Code to http calls to Elastix server in order to get these operations done.

Has anybody already worked with **Elastix Call Center Protocol** in Java? If so, could you give some directions, 'cause everything I've been doing ends up looking like an terrible workaround.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Although I can empathize, this is not a question that is a good fit for the site's Q&A format. My suggestion is that you have a look at the existing questions on the relevant tags, and as well as whatever documentation available. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12230229)

Comment: I sure did.  I think I've already read all available issues about ECCP here.

Comment: Anyway, I would be glad if you give me some directions to fit this question to the site's Q&A .

Comment: Hi Jaumzera, the reason why I say that it is a poor fit is that it is a very broad question which does not have a specific "right" answer. There is some good guidance on asking in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) although none of it is explicitly about "what makes a good question". For advice on this, a good source is [Jon Skeet's blog post on writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Ok, I'll consider your advise and improve the question content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source Eccp2Java project (beta):

https://github.com/xbrain-dev/eccp2java/tree/master/src/main/java/br/com/xbrain/eccp2java